# Accidentally almost deleted iPhoto library

Tags: photos.app, data-recovery

I was emptying out folders and deleting unnecessary items and as I went to my pictures folder I simply just dragged everything to the trash not knowing that my whole iPhoto library was there.

When I hit empty trash a couple of seconds later I had realized what I had done and I hit cancel as it was in the process of deleting. Now when I try to open iPhoto it says "Your photo library is either in use by another application or has become unreadable". When I look at my picture space, it still basically has all the GB there, just a few missing.

Are my pictures still retrievable?

Answer (score 2):

If you purely want to salvage your photos, then this is the easiest way without any other software.

1. Right-click on the iPhoto Library file and select **Show Package Contents**
   [image]
2. Find the **Masters** folder and copy it somewhere, like your *Desktop*
   [image]
3. Hold down <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> key and open iPhoto again. This will bring up this window
   [image]
4. Select **New Library** and import all the photos from the *Masters* folder that you copied to your Desktop in step #2

This should work, and create a new library with any photos that are still intact.